# Sending 9000/s push notifications for iOS

Tags: python, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My system has about 10000 iOS users and i want to send them a push notification but without taking time as i may send another message after 5 minutes or less for the same user,
I read this answer before which also founded in Apple Site:

> Push Notification Throughput and Error Checking
>
> There are no caps or batch size limits for using APNs. The iOS 6.1
>   press release stated that APNs has sent over 4 trillion push
>   notifications since it was established. It was announced at WWDC 2012
>   that APNs is sending 7 billion notifications daily.
>
> If you're seeing throughput lower than 9,000 notifications per second,
>   your server might benefit from improved error handling logic.

But a don't know how to send 9000/s message while i'm sending the notification one by one.

I'm using Python (PyAPNs) and this is my code:

```
from apns import APNs,Payload
result = execute("SELECT token_hex FROM `Users`")
for row in result:
    token_hex = row['token_hex']
    apns = APNs(use_sandbox=False, cert_file='Cert.pem', key_file='CertKey.pem')
    payload = Payload(alert="Message",badge=1,sound='default')
    apns.gateway_server.send_notification(token_hex, payload)
```

I'm sending to 10000 users in more than 30 minutes...

So what is the problem in my code or what can i do to send the notification in less time...

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know python but looking at your code it looks like you are duplicating calls unnecessarily. You should use the same connection for sending all the notifications.

Perhaps you should try something like this :

```
from apns import APNs,Payload
result = execute("SELECT token_hex FROM `Users`")
apns = APNs(use_sandbox=False, cert_file='Cert.pem', key_file='CertKey.pem')
payload = Payload(alert="Message",badge=1,sound='default')
for row in result:
    token_hex = row['token_hex']
    apns.gateway_server.send_notification(token_hex, payload)
```

This is assuming you are sending the same notification payload to all your devices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know it will make it faster but also it will not send 9000/s as they said in the documentation...
it will take about 2 minutes to send to 9000 users